# How to manually configure directory of spring boot project in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to add an existing spring boot project into my Intellij collection project as a module.

Obviously if I open the spring boot project by itself, everything is configured correctly, but it's not configured correctly if I copy a spring boot project directly into the directory of the collection project where the modules go.

After I manually mark the directory as a sources root, I still need to set the classpath the way it would've been setup if importing the spring boot project directly.

What is the easiest way to finish configuring Project Structure for the directory so that it would work as if it was imported directly?

Comment: Do you use any build system, that supports modules (like Gradle or Maven)?

Comment: No, I would not build the "master" collection project, it's just a project to hold all the spring boot projects, as "modules". but I wouldn't implement them as modules, only as storage.   If there's a better way to do this, let me know...

Comment: You can try to close the IDE, backup and delete all .iml files from your Spring project, open your main project in the IDE and use [Import a module from existing sources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#import-module-from-sources) to add your Spring project as a module.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov that was the answer I was looking for. If you can add this an an answer then I can accept as the accepted answer...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to close the IDE, backup and delete all `.iml` files from your Spring project, open your main project in the IDE and use [Import a module from existing sources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#import-module-from-sources) to add your Spring project as a module.